# Cómo devolver la palabra más larga en python?

Tags: python

Subo mi estructura de desarrollo para ver si me pueden orientar(sepan entender que soy novata en esto y me cuesta mucho). [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Bianca, bienvenida. Tu pregunta no sigue las normas del sitio (y es posible que sea cerrada), pues se trata de una tarea de clase para la que debes mostrar qué has intentado y plantear qué duda concreta te ha surgido, en lugar de poner el enunciado y esperar que alguien lo resuelva. Además no debes poner código como imágenes. Mira el [recorrido](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) que contiene consejos sobre cómo hacer buenas preguntas que sean bien recibidas y así obtener respuestas. Por otro lado, investiga [`str.split()`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/stdtypes.html#str.split)

Answer (score 1):

Esto podría apoyarte:

```
    def searchWord(str):
        string = []
        text = str.split(" ")

        for x in text:
            string.append(x)
            #return string

        for i in reversed(sorted(string, key=len)):
            print(i)

    str = "Maria tenia un corderito llamado pepe"

    print(searchWord(str))
```

Te dejo también algunas ligas de interés respecto al tema que buscas apoyo.

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/find-words-greater-given-length-k/

https://pynative.com/python-random-choice/

Saludos.

Comment: amigo no le "hagas la tarea" porque aquí son bien especiales y te llenarán de votos negativos en todos tus posts.